# Starting remote SSH session from Deployer inside Docker

Tags: docker, ssh, php-deployer

I am trying to add an additional script to my PHP deployer script to open an SSH session on my hosting server.

Amongst the welcome message from the remote server, there is an error message:

**the input device is not a TTY**

Then I get an "exit code 1 (General error)" at the end, and it exits back to my local docker terminal.

Here is my script so far:

```
task('remotessh', function () {
    $host = currentHost();

    $hostname = $host->getHostname();
    $remoteUser = $host->get('remote_user');

    if (!$remoteUser) {
        throw new \RuntimeException("Remote user not set for host.");
    }

    $sshCommand = "ssh -T $remoteUser@$hostname";
    runLocally($sshCommand, ['tty' => true]);
});
```

Note: when I manually run `ssh {remoteUser}@{hostname}` in the same docker terminal, I can start an ssh session just fine.

Note 2: when I add -v flag there is some relevant output:

```
[server.com] err debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:xxx
[server.com] err debug1: Server accepts key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:xxx
[server.com] err debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
[server.com] err Authenticated to server.com ([IP Address]:22).
[server.com] err debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
[server.com] err debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
[server.com] err debug1: Entering interactive session.
[server.com] err debug1: pledge: network
[server.com] err debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
[server.com] err debug1: Remote: /data/docker0/ssh/user/login/.ssh/authorized_keys:6: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
[server.com] err debug1: Remote: /data/docker0/ssh/user/login/.ssh/authorized_keys:6: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
[server.com] err debug1: Sending environment.
[server.com] err the input device is not a TTY
```

Any ideas how I can get this running?

Comment: What do you get if you add `-v` to that SSH command? Does it mention the presence or absence of keys?

Comment: There is logging saying it successfully authenticates, and that the key has been accepted- see my edit. I also get the regular login welcome message from my server too.

Comment: Is there anything in the remote user's shell startup files (_.bashrc_ and similar) that starts docker? Please [edit] your question to include anything from their shell startup files that might start docker or another unusual command.

Answer (score 0):

To forcibly allocate a TTY you have to specify `-t`. From the ssh manual page

> Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services. Multiple `-t` options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

So in my opinion you have to use

```
$sshCommand = "ssh -t $remoteUser@$hostname";
runLocally($sshCommand, ['tty' => true]);
```

Maybe you have to specify `ssh -ttt $remoteUser@$hostname`.

Comment: Running with `-ttt` doesn't make  a difference unfortunately, I still get the "input device is not a TTY" error

Answer (score 0):

First, note that if the TTY is not strictly necessary for what you need to do on the remote server, you could modify your SSH command to *not* require a TTY.

```php
$sshCommand = "ssh -T $remoteUser@$hostname";
runLocally($sshCommand);
```

The `-T` flag explicitly tells SSH not to allocate a pseudo-terminal.

But if you do need said terminal, and if using `-tt` in the SSH command does not resolve the "`input device is not a TTY`" error, try and use the [`script` command](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/script-command-in-linux-with-examples/) to emulate a terminal (TTY). That can be particularly useful when running commands in environments that lack TTY, like Docker containers or CI/CD pipelines.

Modify your script as follows:

```php
task('remotessh', function () {
    $host = currentHost();
    $hostname = $host->getHostname();
    $remoteUser = $host->get('remote_user');

    if (!$remoteUser) {
        throw new \RuntimeException("Remote user not set for host.");
    }

    $sshCommand = "script -q -c \"ssh $remoteUser@$hostname\" /dev/null";
    runLocally($sshCommand, ['tty' => true]);
});
```

If you have control over how the Docker container is run, you can try allocating a pseudo-TTY at the Docker level.

For example, when running the container, use:

```
docker run -it (rest of your Docker command)
```

The [`-it` flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#name) allocates an interactive terminal when the Docker container is run.

Make sure the environment from which the PHP script is run (i.e., the Docker container) supports interactive sessions.
Check the SSH client configuration (typically found in `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`) for any settings that might affect TTY allocation (like, for instance, [`RequestTTY`](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/r/requesttty.htm)).